# How to access local variable in the global scope PHP?

Tags: php, variables, scope

I've been trying to access a local variable inside of the global scope. I've tried the `global $var` method but that doesn't seem to work. 
The variable I'm trying to access is the `$word1Txt` variable.
Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Word" name="word1" autofocus>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Second Word" name="word2" autofocus>
                        <input class="btn btn-primary form-submit" type="submit" value="Compare">
                    </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
            require('./wordnik/Swagger.php');
            $APIKey = '342eac9900e703079b0050d5f7008eab962195189e75bfbcb';
            $client = new APIClient($APIKey, 'http://api.wordnik.com/v4');

            if (!empty($_POST['word1'])) {
                $word1 = $_POST['word1'];
                $wordApi = new WordApi($client);
                $word1 = $wordApi->getDefinitions($word1, null, null, 1);
                global $word1Txt; 
                global $word10;
                $word1Txt = $_POST['word1'];
                $word10 = $word1[0]->text;
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['word2'])) {
                $word2 = $_POST['word2'];
                $wordApi = new WordApi($client);
                $word2 = $wordApi->getDefinitions($word2, null, null, 1);
                global $word2Txt; 
                global $word20;
                $word2Txt = $_POST['word2'];
                $word20 = $word2[0]->text;
            }
            print $word1Txt;
        ?>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var word1Txt = <?php echo $word1Txt; ?>;
                var word2Txt = <?php echo $word2Txt; ?>;  

                $('div.word1').prepend("<h3 class='header'>hi" + word1Txt + "</h3>");
                $('div.word2').prepend("<h3 class='header'>hi" + word2Txt + "</h3>");
            });
```

EDIT:
I tried adding var_dump($_POST); in front of if statements. I get the following output.

```
array(2) { ["word1"]=> string(2) "hi" ["word2"]=> string(2) "no" } 

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unauthorized API request to
http://api.wordnik.com/v4/word.json/hi/definitions?limit=1:
unauthorized in
C:\xampp\htdocs\DictionaryCompare\wordnik\Swagger.php:111 Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\DictionaryCompare\wordnik\WordApi.php(176): APIClient->callAPI('/word.json/hi/d...', 'GET', Array, NULL, Array) #1
C:\xampp\htdocs\DictionaryCompare\index.php(40):
WordApi->getDefinitions('hi', NULL, NULL, 1) #2 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\DictionaryCompare\wordnik\Swagger.php on line 111
```

Comment: not sure what the problem is - what var are you trying to access and where?

Comment: @WEBjuju Sorry about that. I edited my question. Let me know if you need anymore info :)

Comment: It doesn't look like you should need global with this code. There is only one scope in what you've included here.

Comment: @Don'tPanic well what I'm actually try to do is pass that variable to JS via the `var word1Txt = <?php echo $word1Txt; ?>;` method. But for that to work I need the `$word1Txt` variable in the global scope, unless you have another idea.

Comment: As fas as what I see here, `$word1Txt` _is_ global. _Everything_ is global. You don't have any classes/functions there, so the scope never changes. The scope doesn't change inside an `if` block.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Oh. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you have right values in your `$_POST` or not but this is noting to do with scope since as you see this works!

```
$_POST['word1'] = 'word1';
$_POST['word2'] = 'word2';
var_dump($_POST); // here you make sure you have posted right values 

// array(2) { ["word1"]=> string(5) "word1" ["word2"]=> string(5) "word2" } <---- this should have values

            if (!empty($_POST['word1'])) {
                $word1 = $_POST['word1'];

                global $word1Txt; 
                global $word10;
                $word1Txt = $_POST['word1'];
                $word10 = $word1[0]->text;
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['word2'])) {
                $word2 = $_POST['word2'];
                global $word2Txt; 
                global $word20;
                $word2Txt = $_POST['word2'];
                $word20 = $word2[0]->text;
            }
            print $word1Txt;
        ?>
```

So make sure you have right values in `$_POST` by using `var_dump($_POST)` just before IF statements.

Update: Here we are, You missed the `action` attribute :)!

```
 <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="result.php">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Word" name="word1" autofocus>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Second Word" name="word2" autofocus>
                            <input class="btn btn-primary form-submit" type="submit" value="Compare">
                        </form>
```

Comment: I apologize but I'm very new to PHP and don't quite understand what you want me to do?

Comment: I guess $_POST['word1'] and $_POST['word2'] are both empty so that is why you don't have value in $word1Txt

Comment: Sorry, I'll upload the full code. I have an HTML form that submits data to that post. That I'm sure works.

Comment: put the output of var_dump($_POST) before if statements.

Comment: You missed the 'action' in your form

Comment: That helped. But I'm still getting an issue.  I'll post output in question,

Comment: @Njinx , Make sure your API key is right and you are using it right cause this issue is related to your API call, not vars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128881/discussion-between-farzad-salimi-jazi-and-njinx).

Answer (score 0):

There is a global variable (excuse the pun) named `$GLOBALS`. See the official [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php).

```
// in the middle of some context
$GLOBALS['foo'] = 'some text';
// in another context and scope, in the same run
echo $GLOBALS['foo'];
// echoes `some text`
```